# Ansible replace all occurrences in windows text file - win_lineinfile

Tags: ansible

win_lineinfile, as per Ansible docs

> ... the pattern to replace if found; only the last line found will be replaced

sometimes all you want to do is replace all instances of a string in all lines with another string

```
- name: replace thin with oci in environment.properties
  win_shell: |
    (Get-Content "{{file_name}}").replace(':thin:',':oci:') | Set-Content -Path "{{file_name}}" -Encoding Ascii
```

yes, templates are a better option in many cases

Is there a better native Ansible way to do this in Windows?

Comment: I don't have a better solution, so I'm using yours.  Thanks!

Comment: which isn't a windows module ....

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use:

```
  win_lineinfile:
      path: 'your/path/to/file.ext'
      # Line to Search/Match against
      regexp: '{{item.From}}'
      # Line to Replace with
      line: '{{item.To}}'
      backrefs: yes
```

The backrefs option allows you to search in the entire file. More info here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/win_lineinfile_module.html

Comment: this is good, and how i did it, except that if you have more than one line that the regex searches for, then it only replaces the last line.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question **Lola**, yes good question and yes it would work, but you likely will run into problems with win_lineinfile since it's an in-line replacement and Configs can be more complex.

**Straff**, I would use win_powershell instead. Often these file operations need elevated privileges to copy or write to files due to the PowerShell restrictions. I think they are universal and work with a lot of the modules.

To specify elevated privileges you'll need to pass the params for **become**, **become_method: runas**, and then the **become_flags** for the type of credentials. So in the example below (***assuming that the credentials are for an AD account***). You also need to add the ***vars:*** for the **ansible_become_user** and **ansible_become_pass**.

```
- name: replace thin with oci in environment.properties
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      (Get-Content "{{file_name}}").replace(':thin:',':oci:') | Set-Content -Path "{{file_name}}" -Encoding Ascii
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: 
    logon_type=new_credentials
    logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: 'user@domain.com'
    ansible_become_pass: 'yourpassword'
```

**NOTE**: You need to upgrade ansible to **version 2.5 or newer** to apply these features in windows.

Comment: I dont like the idea of having to use PS for ansible commands, but this is one case that obviously justifies it, when you have multiple lines of the same replace... where win_lineinfile is currently bugged to only replace the last line that it finds for each regex entry unfortunately. Thanks! `$txt -replace '(CONNECTION_STRING.*Server=)(uniquename((?!ctujldgrtee3).)*.com)(;DataBase.*$?)','$1XXXXXXXXXXXXX$4' 
`